# Ionic Cordova Run poiting to another emulator on --target

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator, genymotion

I have a device built in genymotion which I'm trying to run an ionic app.
My devices list (with adb devices):

**emulator-5562
myDevice - device**

When I run "ionic cordova run android --device" or ionic cordova run android --target = myDevice" it always happens to give me the response:

```
**[native-run] Error: Command failed: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb -s emulator-5562 shell getprop**

**[native-run] error: device offline**
```

My problem is: I don't even have this emulator-5562, I already deleted every single emulator that I have, searched for this folder mentioned above, and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you want to target a device or you dont want to target it. ? If you dont want to target it then run "onic cordova run android"

Comment: @Swayangjit I want to target it, but it keeps telling me that the device that I didn't target is offline (as if I had used target in the other device), so the run fails

Comment: How you have deleted the emulator?

Comment: Have you started the device in Genymotion Desktop? What's its name?